# Computing the Krull dimension of a completed group algebra

Tags: commutative-algebra, p-adic-number-theory

Let $\Gamma$ be a pro-$p$ abelian group. Is it true that the Krull dimension of the completed group algebra $\mathbb F_p[[\Gamma]]$ is equal to the $\mathbb Z_p$-rank of $\Gamma$?

If $\Gamma\simeq \mathbb Z_p^r$, then the completed group algebra is isomorphic to the ring of power series: $\mathbb Z_p[[\Gamma]]\simeq \mathbb Z_p[[T_1,\ldots,T_r]]$ (cf. e.g. 5.3.5. of Neukirch–Schmidt–Wingberg). Quotienting out by $p$, we get that $\mathbb F_p[[\Gamma]]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb F_p[[T_1,\ldots,T_r]]$, which has Krull dimension $r$, which is what we wanted.

What happens if $\Gamma$ also has a torsion part?

Comment: Let $\Gamma=F \oplus T$ with $F$ free and $T$ torsion, then $\mathbb{Z}_p[[F]] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_p[[\Gamma]]$ should be injective finite, no?

Comment: Injectivity indeed follows from the left exactness of inverse limits. I don’t think finiteness holds: let $T$ be product of countably infinitely many copies of the cyclic group of order $p$, and let $F=0$. Then not even $T$ is finitely generated over $F$, and I think the same is true for the completed group algebras.

Comment: Oops, good point. I guess I was thinking of the case where $T$ was finitely generated over $\mathbb{F}_p$, but it’s indeed far from the only case…